# Как протестировать после падения нетбук с SSD?

Tags: ssd, железо

Вопрос банальный, но все же.Упал нетбук eepc 1000HE с высоты ~1600 мм с ускорением при падении. Падал в чехле из смягчающего материала (стандартная поставка в комплекте с нетбуком) и пакете обычном полиэтиленовом. В нетбуке есть ssd OCZ-VERTEX2. Явных признаков разбитого железа нет, но дисковый ответ начал, по ощущениям от работы ПО всякого, подтормаживать.

Можно ли протестировать железо софтом, каким лучше, на что прежде всего обратить внимание? Пока я использовала atop, явных задержек ответа диска не выявила. Есть предположение, что есть трещины в самой матери. В dmesg критических сообщений тоже не выявлено.

Дистрибутив ArchLinux.

К амперметру и прочим аппаратным средствам тестирования пока, пожалуйста, не отсылайте, такого оборудования у меня все равно нет.

Comment: mhdd ssd накопители разве не тестит?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы не ориентируетесь в вопросе профессионального глубокого тестирования аппаратного обеспечения, то лучше обратитесь к соответствующим специалистам.

Ну действительно, нет такой волшебной программки, которая по одному клику мышки напишет, что у вас микротрещина в матплате, НЕТ!!!..

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но можно же протестировать скорость ответа от основных компонентов, скорость шин, разве нет?